# How to display county tooltip in d3 map?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to create a tooltip in a D3 map. (also using DC.js). The problem is that it seems that the DC chart (mexicoChart) which holds the map is above everything or it is not compatible with the following code 
(Nothing happens after adding it):

```
var width = 960 
var height = 500 
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
 .scale(1200)
    .center([-102.34034978813841, 24.012062015793]);    
var path = d3.geo.path()
             .projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .style("width", 600);

var g = svg.append("g");



d3.json("static/geojson/mx_tj.json", function(error, mx) {
  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(mx, mx.objects.municipalities))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
    .attr("fill", "transparent")
    .style("stroke", "#333")
    .style("stroke-width", ".2px")
    .attr("class", "muns");

  g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(mx, mx.objects.states))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
    .attr("fill", "transparent")
    .style("stroke", "#333");

 svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "muns")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(mx, mx.objects.municipalities))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {var tip = "<h3>" + d.properties.name + "</h3>";
    tooltip.html(tip)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");

    tooltip.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", .7); })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {  tooltip.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });



});
```

This is the second part of the code where the DC Charts are:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/homicidios/projects")
    .defer(d3.json, "static/geojson/municipios.json")
    .await(makeGraphs);




function makeGraphs(error, projectsJson, mx) {

    //Clean projectsJson data
    var homicidiosProjects = projectsJson;
    var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    homicidiosProjects.forEach(function(d) {
        d["fecha"] = dateFormat.parse(d["fecha"]);
        d["fecha"].setMinutes(0);
        d["fecha"].setSeconds(0);
        //  d["no_muertos"] = +d["no_muertos"];
    });

    //Create a Crossfilter instance
    var ndx = crossfilter(homicidiosProjects);

    //Define Dimensions
    var FechaDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d["fecha"];
    });
    var zonaDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d["entidad_federativa"];
    });
    var pobrezaDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d["marginacion"];
    });
    var MunDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d["CVE_MUN"];
    });
    var noMuertosDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d["no_muertos"];
    });


    //Calculate metrics
    var numProjectsPorFecha = FechaDim.group();
    var numProjectsPorZona = zonaDim.group();
    var numProjectsPorPobreza = pobrezaDim.group();
    var noMuertosPorMun = MunDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
        return d["no_muertos"];
    });

    var all = ndx.groupAll();
    var noMuertos = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {
        return d["no_muertos"];
    });

    var max_mun = noMuertosPorMun.top(1)[0].value;

    //Define values (to be used in charts)
    var minDate = FechaDim.bottom(1)[0]["fecha"];
    var maxDate = FechaDim.top(1)[0]["fecha"];

    //Charts
    var timeChart = dc.barChart("#time-chart");
    var zonaChart = dc.rowChart("#zona-row-chart");
    var pobrezaChart = dc.rowChart("#pobreza-row-chart");
    var mexicoChart = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#mexico-Chart");
    var numberProjectsND = dc.numberDisplay("#number-projects-nd");
    var noMuertosND = dc.numberDisplay("#no-muertos-nd");



    numberProjectsND
        .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .group(all);

    noMuertosND
        .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .group(noMuertos)
        .formatNumber(d3.format(".3s"));

    timeChart
        .width(1000)
        .height(180)
        .margins({
            top: 10,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 50
        })
        .dimension(FechaDim)
        .group(numProjectsPorFecha)
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .xAxisLabel("Dia")
        .yAxis().ticks(10);

    zonaChart
        .width(300)
        .height(350)
        .dimension(zonaDim)
        .group(numProjectsPorZona)
        .xAxis().ticks(4);

    pobrezaChart
        .width(300)
        .height(250)
        .dimension(pobrezaDim)
        .group(numProjectsPorPobreza)
        .xAxis().ticks(4);


    d3.json("static/geojson/municipios.json", function (error, mx) { 


    mexicoChart.width(1000)
        .height(630)
        .dimension(MunDim)
        .group(noMuertosPorMun)


        .colors(["#FFE5EC", "#FFCCD9", "#FFB2C6", "#FF99B3", "#FF7FA0", "#FF668D", "#FF4C7A", "#FF3367", "#FF1954", "#FF0041"])
        .colorDomain([0, max_mun])
        .overlayGeoJson(mx.features, "municipio", function(d) {
            return d.properties.CVE_MUN;
        })

        .projection(d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([-101.45, 19.28])
            .scale(1600)
            .translate([490, 490]))
        .title(function(p) {
            return "State: " + p["key"] + 
                "\n" +
                "Total Muertos: " + Math.round(p["value"]) + " $";
        })



dc.renderAll();


});

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where the tooltip code came from, but it looks like you've pasted something that is supposed to be an event handler into the data handler - for example I don't think `d3.event.pageX` has any meaning when responding to `d3.json`

Comment: The geoChoroplethChart has a built-in tooltip which you can see [hovering on this map](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/index.html). I guess you are trying to get something like [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) working with it? It's hard for me to try it out without a running example, but I think you could perhaps run the `tooltip` code that is supposed to place and fade in the div, inside of a mouseover event handler on the choropleth?

Comment: Oh I get it you are overlaying a straight D3 map on top of, or below a dc.js geoChoroplethChart. That's tricky! If you create a running example it will be easier for folks to help you. This is not likely to be something people can diagnose just by staring at the code.